# Create Highcharts bubble chart dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts, bubble-chart

i'm trying to create a script that will generate, with a JSON object, a bubble chart dynamically.

This is an example of the JSON obtained after an Ajax Call.

```
 {  
   "Result":"OK",
   "chartOptions":{  
      "title":"Review Data",
      "subtitle":"",
      "graph_title":"bubble"
   },
   "xAxisOption":{  
      "categories":[  
         "January",
         "February",
         "March",
         "April",
         "May",
         "June",
         "July",
         "August",
         "September"
      ]
   },
   "yAxisOption":{  
      "title":"Days"
   },
   "Records":{  
      "A":[  
         "[3,1,20.84],[3,15,119.90],[6,13,22.46],[6,21,240.00],[6,16,5.99],[9,13,60.00],[1,30,104.95],[1,22,69.65],[1,4,101.48],[2,1,63.30],[4,17,70.05],[4,19,19.74],[4,13,36.28],[4,18,22.46],[7,25,61.56],[7,6,83.16],[8,12,8.00],[8,9,60.00],[5,2,80.00],[5,27,30.00]"
      ],
      "B":[  
         "[3,7,133.24],[6,18,250.00],[6,13,11.35],[6,25,98.00],[6,3,215.95],[9,5,48.32],[9,26,68.79],[1,27,38.89],[1,4,12.50],[1,29,62.50],[2,19,60.00],[4,8,288.70],[7,10,17.85],[7,6,15.04],[8,11,8.80],[8,17,108.10],[8,16,30.27]"
      ],
      "C":[  
         "[3,14,28.83],[6,20,66.70],[9,13,73.00],[9,19,32.00],[9,8,15.28],[9,17,18.40],[1,7,71.00],[1,26,90.00],[1,23,13.35],[2,15,10.49],[2,8,12.99],[4,19,70.76],[4,13,34.00],[7,15,65.97],[7,28,60.00],[8,14,21.85],[8,10,143.64],[5,10,68.22]"
      ],
      "D":[  
         "[3,9,95.00],[3,6,21.00],[3,15,24.46],[6,23,18.00],[6,6,50.00],[6,22,23.41],[6,5,22.40],[6,25,28.00],[6,15,37.36],[9,28,89.61],[9,10,14.50],[1,26,10.33],[2,8,133.80],[2,27,39.20],[2,6,47.99],[2,20,65.69],[5,25,100.00],[5,10,85.70]"
      ],
      "E":[  
         "[3,31,62.50],[3,23,77.05],[3,19,9.10],[6,25,29.84],[6,15,43.90],[6,22,10.90],[6,3,78.57],[6,18,120.00],[9,16,65.68],[9,12,32.42],[1,17,15.20],[2,21,100.41],[2,6,72.83],[4,25,80.00],[7,13,11.92],[8,2,28.40],[8,30,90.00],[8,23,21.05],[5,25,7.54],[5,14,299.00]"
      ],
      "F":[  
         "[3,18,63.68],[3,22,29.54],[3,19,16.40],[6,28,82.40],[6,12,19.60],[9,7,22.00],[9,19,30.00],[9,13,37.02],[9,28,10.00],[1,2,60.00],[2,8,7.80],[4,2,65.44],[7,6,210.00],[7,2,14.50],[8,10,49.30],[8,23,56.35],[5,2,14.90],[5,24,7.92],[5,10,11.89]"
      ],
      "G":[  
         "[3,8,14.95],[6,16,6.00],[6,25,45.00],[6,14,89.20],[6,23,58.18],[9,28,19.35],[4,19,51.03],[4,6,120.00],[7,13,65.79],[7,1,67.87],[7,26,79.00],[8,16,29.18],[8,2,29.00],[8,26,70.28],[5,18,50.00],[5,7,69.40]"
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried a lot of ways, but none of them worked.

For example, i tried

```
$.each(msg.Records, function(key, value) {
    chart.series.push({
        data: value,
        name: key
    });
});
```

or

```
$.each(msg.Records, function(key, value) {
    chart.addSeries({
        data: value,
        name: key
    });
});
```

Hope somebody will help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is a little bit invalid:

```
 "A":[  
     "[3,1,20.84],[3,15,119.90],[6,13,22.46],[6,21,240.00],[6,16,5.99],[9,13,60.00],[1,30,104.95],[1,22,69.65],[1,4,101.48],[2,1,63.30],[4,17,70.05],[4,19,19.74],[4,13,36.28],[4,18,22.46],[7,25,61.56],[7,6,83.16],[8,12,8.00],[8,9,60.00],[5,2,80.00],[5,27,30.00]"
     ]
```

Is an array of a single string, when I think you meant it to be an array of arrays.  Fix this on the backend if you can.

If you can't fix it on the backend, it is possible to do in JavaScript:

```
var options = {
  chart:{
    type: 'bubble'
  },
  series: []
};

$.each(msg.Records, function(key, value) {
    options.series.push({
        data: $.parseJSON("["+value[0]+"]"), // <-- make it a "correct" string and then parse it
        name: key
    });
});

$('#container').highcharts(options);
```

Here's a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TsW4expaHqxP73sKA1XO?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the Javascript solution and it worked perfectly. I will try to use the backend solution as soon as possible because the other one, as you suggest, need to rebuild the chart ($('#container').highcharts(options);). My script (sorry i didn't explain this) change chart to the one needed in different choice, and until now i didn't have to declare them everytime, i just changed the variables and datas. But well, just a little change, and now it's working.